# How can i back up azure databricks workspace

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I want backup the entire workspace for disaster recovery and as backup
better if i can automate it with python or terraform

i have tryed to automate it with python but not able to find sucess

and i am not able to find a proper documentation to it also

Comment: https://github.com/databrickslabs/migrate#databricks-migration-tool
can you check this if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

To prepare for regional disasters, you need to explicitly maintain another set of Azure Databricks workspaces in a secondary region.

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/howto-regional-disaster-recovery#regional-disaster) tools for disaster recovery are mainly Terraform (for Infra replication) and Delta Deep Clone (for Data replication).

[Detailed migration steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/howto-regional-disaster-recovery#detailed-migration-steps) will help you with the below:

- Set up the Databricks command-line interface on your computer
- Configure two profiles.
- Migrate Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory) users
- Migrate the user folders and notebooks
- Migrate the cluster configurations
- Migrate the jobs configuration
- Migrate libraries
- Migrate Azure blob storage and Azure Data Lake Storage mounts
- Migrate cluster init scripts
- Manually reconfigure and reapply access control.

***Note :Libraries are not copied over in this step, as the underlying API doesn't support those.***

***- Unfortunately there is no create cluster config endpoint, and this script tries to create each cluster right away. If there aren't enough cores available in your subscription, the cluster creation may fail.  The failure can be ignored, as long as the configuration is transferred successfully.***